# BusyBox - Bash signal handler 'echo' issue

Tags: bash, shell-script, busybox

I have a Bash script that begins by opening a TCP client socket using `nc` and sending a start command over that socket. The server then sends me back data over the socket (which `nc` prints to `stdout`), and when the user is satisfied with the data they've seen, they press Ctrl+C, and the script is supposed to send a stop command over the socket to tell the server to stop doing what it's doing.

To keep the `nc` socket open for an arbitrary amount of time, I open a FIFO and `tail -n +1 -f` from that FIFO into `nc`, and so to send commands over the socket, the script simply `echo`es to the FIFO.

But after my signal handler executes, the `echo` call that sends the stop command hangs/freezes and never returns, and so the script just sits there.

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
#! /bin/bash

# make a FIFO to use as STDIN for netcat
FIFO=/tmp/temp_fifo
mkfifo $FIFO

# open up the client socket
TAIL_PID_FILE=/tmp/tail_pid
(tail -n +1 -f $FIFO & echo $! >&3) 3> $TAIL_PID_FILE | /usr/bin/nc some_server 9999 &

# get PID of tail process
TAIL_PID=$(<$TAIL_PID_FILE)

# send the start command to tell the server to start doing its work
echo "start command" >> $FIFO

# register a signal handler so that we wait until the user presses Ctrl+C
trap "echo caught signal, stopping..." SIGINT SIGTERM

# sleep 'forever' (until the signal gets caught)
sleep 4294967295

# send the stop command. ***this right here is what hangs***
echo "stop command" >> $FIFO

# kill tail process
kill $TAIL_PID

# remove FIFO
rm -f $FIFO
```

When running this in Linux, in Bash version 4.1.2, this runs normally--i.e. the `echo` doesn't hang and so the stop command gets sent successfully. But BusyBox (version 1.22.1, in Windows/MobaXterm) hangs on it.

Am I doing something wrong here (e.g. undefined behavior) with respect to my signal handler, hence why my code doesn't work in BusyBox? Or does this maybe hint at a bug or missing feature that I'm unaware of in BusyBox?

Comment: If the echo hangs, it is probable that the fifo has been closed. Perhaps your signal is propagating to the tail or nc command and killing one of them. You might try the bash `disown` command?

Comment: @meuh You may be on the right track here, i.e. that something's going on with the `tail` process. Doing `disown $TAIL_PID` right after I set the variable (before I send the start command) yields `./script.sh: line xx: disown: 12052: no such job`. But doing a `disown` on the `nc` PID doesn't emit that error message

Comment: Try a `disown` inside the `()` right after the `&` of the `tail` command. You might also have the `setsid` command to isolate a process.

Comment: How could I do that and still get the `tail` PID? If I put `disown` right after the `&`, I can't do `echo $! >&3`

Comment: `$!` should still be set. If it doesnt, do it after the echo.

Comment: I changed `FIFO` to be a regular file instead of a pipe, and the code works flawlessly...maybe `tail` has some funky behavior with named pipes in BusyBox?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the simple tail (which busybox picks and executes) to something similar to `/usr/bin/tail`? Good luck.